# multiple Toggle event for multiple divs

Tags: jquery

here is my requirements.
here when i click buynow i want to disable this button and want to show content and when i click again content then i want to hide this content and want to show buynow text.

```
<div class="btn button-success" >Buy Now</div>
<div class="book" style="display: none;">
 content
</div>

<div class="btn button-success" >Buy Now</div>
<div class="book" style="display: none;">
 content
</div>



  am used below script its working but in browser hiding is not looking good.

   $(".btn").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next(".book").toggle();
    });
    $(".book").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev(".btn").toggle();
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'want to show book class', and have tried anything on your own/

Comment: i tried several ways but not got solution. tried to use toggle function but its not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have clicked event on `disable` button. So,to overcome this you can add custom css to some class using `addClass` or `removeClass` and make button look like disable .Also, i have use `toggle` to show or hide your div.

**Demo Code** :

```js
//onclick of button
$('.btn').click(function() {
  //checking if button has disabled class
  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    $(this).removeClass('disabled'); //remove class
    console.log("remove")
  } else {
    console.log("add")
    $(this).addClass('disabled') //add
  }
//button->next->div show
  $(this).next('.book').toggle("show"); //toggle for book div
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: #DDD;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn button-success">Buy Now</button>
<div class="book" style="display: none;">
  content
</div>

<button class="btn button-success">Buy Now</button>
<div class="book" style="display: none;">
  content
</div>

<button class="btn button-success">Buy Now</button>
<div class="book" style="display: none;">
  Content here
</div>

<button class="btn button-success">Buy Now</button>
<div class="book" style="display: none;">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: sorry am modified my code. but actually i want to hide buy now div